# 'IAsyncOperation<BluetoothLEDevice>' does not contain a definition for 'GetGattServicesAsync'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to send bytes to a BLE device via an application developed in C#.

To connect to the device I found this portion of code:

```
    var bluetoothLeDevice = BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync("bluetooth address");
    bluetoothLeDevice.GetGattServicesAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
```

But I have a compilation error on the "GetGattServicesAsync()" method:

```
    'IAsyncOperation<BluetoothLEDevice>' does not contain a definition for 'GetGattServicesAsync' and no accessible extension method 'GetGattServicesAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'IAsyncOperation<BluetoothLEDevice>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? )
```

The libraries declared in the source are:

```
    using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement;
    using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth;
```

For the development of this application (C# - .NET - Console Application) I am using VSCode and dotnet sdk (dotnet-sdk-8.0.100-win-x64).

The project file is as follows (csproj):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

   <PropertyGroup>
     <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
     <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.22000.0</TargetFramework>
     <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
     <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
   </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Do I need to install some other libraries?

Thank you